# Why do i get this error - System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Parameter @quantity has no default value.'

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access, datagridview, ado.net

```
Public Sub saveUseditemLog()
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Close()
        End If
        conn.Open()
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            'Place Records in the Datagridview in placeholders
            Dim id = row.Cells(0).Value
            Dim name = row.Cells(1).Value
            Dim unit = row.Cells(2).Value
            Dim quantity = row.Cells(3).Value
            Dim source = row.Cells(4).Value
            Dim price = row.Cells(5).Value
            Dim pname = row.Cells(6).Value
            Dim sname = row.Cells(7).Value
            Dim quantityused = row.Cells(8).Value
            'Insert into useditem logs
            Dim d As String = Date.Now
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Insert Into `SitesUsedItemLog` (`LogDate`, `ItemID`, `ItemName`, `Unit`, `Quantity`, `Source`, `Price`, `ProjectName`, `SiteName`)
                                             Values (@date, @id, @name, @unit, @quantity, @source, @price, @pname, @sname)", conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", d)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit", unit)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", quantityused) '----> need quantity used not current quantity
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@source", source)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pname", pname)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sname", sname)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
        conn.Close()
    End Sub
```

so I have a DataGrid where I will put a value in row.cells(8).value the code works when im putting values on all rows but when I only put a value in specific row I get the error

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Parameter @quantity has no default value.'

If I input values like this it works

[image]

but not if I only put a value in some row.
[image]

Comment: I think the problem could be that the name of parameter is mismatching in code and DB Table
and the filed that is giving the error is set as NOT NULL. double check spellings to make sure this is not the case.

Comment: What exactly is the value and type of quantityused at the point you’re adding the parameter?  Also might want to look at using Parameters.Add() method over .AddWithValue() as it can do unexpected type conversions.

Comment: If `quantityused` happens to be null (`Nothing`), it doesn't go through. As suggested, use `Parameters.Add()` instead of `.AddWithValue()` and pass an acceptable converted value (e.g., `0`), or `DbNull.Value` is that's feasible. -- What kind of database do you have there?

Comment: @Think2826  i dont think its the spelling cause its still working if I put values in all textbox in the datagrid column that required user input and I set Qualities default value in access to 0 and Required to No.

Comment: @Hursey Dim col As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        col.HeaderText = "QUANTITY USED"
        col.Name = "QuantityUsed"
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(8, col)
        DataGridView1.Columns(8).DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "0"

Comment: @Jimi I tried to use Parameters.add() and and the problem is still there, i also try to rewrote the whole code and it doesn`t work same error, but if i try to use fix value or any other cells to to change with quantityused the code works.

Comment: Well, then show the code you have written that uses `Parameters.Add()` and what value you're passing to this Parameter. Did you check whether `quantityused` is null? As mentioned, null values don't pass through -- BTW, why don't you use an `OleDbDataAdpater` to update your database instead of looping the rows of a Control? You shouldn't do that. What is the `DataSource` of your DataGridView? It appears that you have an Access db, why do you use back-ticks to instead of square brackets to specify the name of Columns? -- BTW2, you must not store a Connection object with an Access db.

Comment: @Jimi what do you mean not store a connection object with an access db?

Comment: This: `If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then conn.Close() End If`. Connections must be declared in-place, with an `Using` statement, so each connection is disposed right after  use. Especially with an Access db, you have serious performance problems when you don't. But this is just the tip of the iceberg. -- It's not related to the current problem, but the source of many others. -- You're trying to pass a null value to the query. Note that `Value` and `FormattedValue` are two different things. -- I hope you have `Option Strict` set to `ON`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246366/discussion-between-karl-and-jimi).